# cakephp 3: change class input error

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I build my form template according the documentation. It seemed everything was fine until I get fields errors. Now I have two problems:

1. How can I change the class name of the forms fields when they get error?

Solution:

`$this->loadHelper('Form', [
   'templates' => 'your_template_file',
   'errorClass' => 'your-class',
]);`

2. How can I set `escape => false` in the error-message from cakephp, when the field get error? Because I have icon within that div, such as

```
<div class="error-message"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> My error</div>
```

Well, I got part of th solution. To escape HTML I could put `$this->Form->error('field', null, ['escape' => false]);` in all fields, but it´s a hard manually task. I´d like to keep escape with default of all fields errors. I could edit the FormHelper.php class. However, I think that is not good idea.

My form template is:

```
'formStart'              => '<form {{attrs}} class="form-horizontal" novalidate>',
'inputContainer'         => '{{content}}',
'input'                  => '<input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" {{attrs}} class="form-control"/>',
'checkbox'               => '<input type="checkbox" value="{{value}}" name="{{name}}" {{attrs}}/>',
'textareaContainerError' => '{{content}}',
'textarea'               => '<textarea name="{{name}}" {{attrs}} class="form-control"></textarea>',
'select'                 => '<select name="{{name}}" {{attrs}} class="form-control">{{content}}</select>',
'button'                 => '<button {{attrs}} class="btn btn-primary">{{text}}</button>',
'nestingLabel'           => '{{input}}',
'formGroup'              => '{{input}}',
```

Comment: Change the classname of _which_ fields _exactly_? The actual input fields like `input`, `textarea`, etc? Why did you remove the error container which would have an appropriate `error` class set? And have you removed others too, not only the one for textareas as shown here?

Comment: I could change the class name of all form fields when they get error.
I put errorClass option in the loadHelper:
$this->loadHelper('Form', [
                'templates' => 'admin_form_template',
                'errorClass' => 'another-class',
            ]);

But, the issue number 2, I couldn´t yet. I need to put escape => false for the cakephp doesn´t escape html tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to the second part of the question: you can extend `FormHelper` like in code below, so that *escape* will be set to **false** by default

```
// extended FormHelper, this goes in src/View/Helper
namespace App\View\Helper;
use Cake\View\Helper;

class MyFormHelper extends Helper\FormHelper
{
    public function error($field, $text = null, array $options = []) 
    {
        if (!isset($options['escape'])) {
            $options['escape'] = false;
        }

        return parent::error($field, $text, $options);
    }
}
```

next create alias for this helper in `AppController.php`

```
public $helpers = [
    'Form' => ['className' => 'MyForm']
];
```

this also allows you to add more customization of your own and at any time, you can go back to default implementation of `FormHelper`, just remove that alias from `AppController.php`.

Comment: Very nice! Worked fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For those who wants an 'easy solution' to escape error message on **some** fields, you cant simply set escape options to false :

```
   <?= $this->Form->input('email', [
                                    "label" => "Email",
                                    "error" => [
                                        "escape" => false
                                    ]
                                ]) ?>
```